# Calculate measure involving dates on a factTable with DAX

Tags: pivot-table, dax, powerpivot

I have this problem:
given a "Movements" *factTable* that holds a list of warehouse transactions.

I want to know how many items arrived, how many were shipped (and this is trivial) but also **how many are "In Order" at a particular time** (and this is the difficult part)

So, each line can either be a receipt (it has a positive "qIn" value) or a shipment (positive qOut)

For example a very simple list of records could be:

```
ID  Item    TransactionDate OrderDate   qIn qOut
1   A       2019-01-30      2019-01-10  5   0
2   A       2019-02-20      2019-01-15  3   0
3   A       2019-03-12      2019-01-20  0   6
4   A       2019-03-30      2019-02-20  20  0
```

That means:
On TransactionDate  2019-01-30 Items A has arrived in quantity 5.
The order for this had been created on 2019-01-10: so for that 20 days there was 5 quantity of Item A "ordered".
However, when I watch at the end of January, I should see 0 for this transaction in the "ordered" measure because it arrived on January 30.

Instead, for the second record, at the end of January I should see that a quantity of 3 was "in order", because the actual arrival has been on 2019-02-20.

So, at the end of the line, the Excel pivot table should show a situation similar to this:

```
    Year    2019
    Month   January         February        March
            IN | Ord        IN | Ord        IN | Ord
Item
A           5      3         3    20        20   0
```

The simple measure of qIn is:

```
qIN := SUM(Transactions[qtaIn])
```

The measure of ordered quantity I have elucubrated at the moment (that does nothing!):

```
orderedQty :=
CALCULATE (
    SUMX ( Transactions; Transactions[qIn] );
    DATESBETWEEN (
        Transactions[TransactionDate];
        MINX ( Transactions; Transactions[OrderDate] );
        MAXX ( Transactions; Transactions[TransactionDate] )
    )
)
```

***EDIT***

The "InOrder" measure should be "additive" in the sense that it should not only take into account what has happened in the current month, but also *how much of the InOrder* from past months is yet to be received.

With a picture (but that would be to do...) the whole thing would be clearer, at least from a logic perspective. However, also with a picture, I can't see how to extract "direct measures" from that logic.

Instead, exploiting the measures already provided by @Olly, the problem could be reformulated as:

```
InOrderFromOtherMonths :=  Sum (qIn) where Order Month <> Current Month
```

(i.e. how many are arrived in current month that comes from orders taken in past months)

```
InOrder := Total sum of (ORDER measure)  -  InOrderFromOtherMonths
```

PS.
I have created [an Excel](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cUIPy6zgl6_Adnqwb6nOZ_LHttn-cYXY/view?usp=sharing) file with a little more interesting example.
[image] 
In that file, using the "direct measure picture" the `InOrder` for January would be:
`ID 2 + ID 5 + ID 6` (orders yet *opened* at end of January).
In values = 3+9+17=**29**

With the "indirect" measure would be:

```
Total sum of ORDER = 15+23+12=50
InOrderFromOtherMonths = 6+15=21
InOrder = Total sum of ORDER - InOrderFromOtherMonths = 50 - 21 = **29**
```

Comment: To clarify - using your logic for open orders in January, shouldn't open orders in February be 17 (20 ordered on ID4, - 3 received on ID2) ?

Comment: @Olly, the thing is quite confusing, maybe I can be wrong... However in my opinion open orders on February it's right to be only 20, because the ID2 are received on 20th February. I have restructured the data a bit, I think it's clearer now.

Comment: So, to clarify your measures: IN = sum of qIn where TransactionDate in filtered month. ORDER = sum of qIn where OrderDate in filtered month and TransactionDate NOT in filtered month. Is that the right business logic?

Comment: @Olly, yes what you say seems right! (and it may be an helpful simplification)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Calendar table, including a `YYYY-MM` field. If you don't already have a calendar table, you can automatically create one in PowerPivot: `Design > Date Table > New`

Create an ACTIVE relationship between `Calendar[Date]` and `Transactions[TransactionDate]`

Create an INACTIVE relationship between `Calendar[Date]` and `Transactions[OrderDate]`

[image]

Now create your measures:

**Measure IN:**

```
IN:=SUM ( Transactions[qIn] )
```

**Measure ORDERS:**

```
ORDERS:=
CALCULATE ( 
    SUM ( Transactions[qIn] ),
    USERELATIONSHIP ( 'Calendar'[Date], Transactions[OrderDate] )
)
```

**Measure ORDER:**

```
ORDER:=
IF ( 
    HASONEVALUE ( 'Calendar'[YYYY-MM] ),
    CALCULATE ( 
        [ORDERS], 
        FORMAT ( Transactions[TransactionDate], "YYYY-MM" ) <>  VALUES ( 'Calendar'[YYYY-MM] )
    )
)
```

And pivot to suit:

[image]

### EDIT

After your question edit, I'm finding some of your labels confusing - but try creating the following measures:

Measure: **Ordered**

```
Ordered:=
CALCULATE ( 
    SUM ( Movements[qIn] ),
    USERELATIONSHIP ( 'Calendar'[Date], Movements[OrdDate] )
)
```

Measure: **Received**

```
Received:= SUM ( Movements[qIn] )
```

Measure: **Outstanding**

```
Outstanding:= 
VAR EOMaxDate = 
    EOMONTH ( LASTDATE ( 'Calendar'[Date] ), 0 )
RETURN
    IF ( 
        ISBLANK ( [Ordered] ) && ISBLANK ( [Received] ),
        BLANK(),
        CALCULATE ( 
            [Ordered] - [Received],
            FILTER ( 
                ALL ( 'Calendar'), 
                'Calendar'[Date] <= EOMaxDate
            )
        )   
    )
```

Now use those three measures in your pivot:

[image]

Or, more clearly:

[image]

See https://excel.solutions/so_55596609-2/ for example XLSX file

Comment: Thank you very much, it seems a good solutions, now I have to try to check with running values... It's not so simple also to find a simple data subset to test it, I'll let you know...

Comment: your answer is a big step in the right direction, however there's something more that should be considered. I have updated my question.

Comment: I still find your labels confusing, but I think you're trying to understand Qty Ordered, Qty Received, and cumulative Qty Outstanding. See my edited answer.

Comment: Yes, it's exactly what I was trying to achieve, wonderful solution... Now I could try myself for the next and "real" objective, that is calculate the "symmetrical" measure, taking into account the `qOut` measure. Using that I want to calculate how many Items are "requested" (or pre-allocated) at the end of any month.